# Python: is it possible to boil this down to a single list comprehension?

Tags: list, list-comprehension

This function checks if the given list of integers have numbers 2 unique numbers that add up to the last number in the list.

```
def check_for_sum(snippet: List[int]) -> bool:
    is_valid = False
    for i in snippet[:-1]:
        for i2 in snippet[:-1]:
            if i + i2 == snippet[-1] and i != i2:
                is_valid = True
    return is_valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement this as list comprehension, but it would not make a lot of sense to do so. List comprehensions are best suited for creating new lists, not searching through an existing one.  If you are curious, however, here is what your existing function might look like using a list comprehension:

```
def check_for_sum(snippet: List[int]) -> bool:
    valid_sums = [
        1
        for i in snippet[:-1]
        for i2 in snippet[:-1]
        if i + i2 == snippet[-1] and i != i2
    ]
    return valid_sums
```

Your time would be better spent on optimizing your existing solution to:

1. Eliminate double counting of values in `snippet` caused by starting each iteration of i2 from the beginning of `snippet`.
2. Exit your function once the first solution has been found rather than continuing on until your loops are done.

Here is what that might look like:

```
def check_for_sum(snippet: List[int]) -> bool:
    for index, i in enumerate(snippet[:-2]):
        for i2 in snippet[index + 1:-1]:
            if i + i2 == snippet[-1] and i != i2:
                return True
    return False
```